# Redshift of the Cosmic Microwave Background: increasing or decreasing?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmic-microwave-background, redshift

[image]

$$\dot z\equiv\frac{\mathrm d z}{\mathrm d t_{\text{obs}}}(t_0)=(1+z)H_0-H(z)$$

The picture and equation above are quoted from [Liske et al. (2008)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.1532).

According to the equation, the redshift of the cosmic microwave background radiation is expected to decrease at this point in time.

However, I think the redshift that will be measured in the future will increase.

Doesn't this equation apply to the cosmic background radiation?

Comment: It is doubtful that mankind will exist for long enough to be able to measure any change in redshift

Comment: @Thomas. Yes. If i look at the paper on the wrong concept of cosmology, it says as you say about the way I refer to it. As you said, it seems to be a theory-based prediction, not observation.

Comment: @anna v. thanks but It says your link is invalid. The address doesn't show up.

Comment: corrected. see this plot to see when CMB starts at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:History_of_the_Universe.svg 380.000 years after the big bang

Comment: For (doubting) @Thomas: https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.05151 http://research.iac.es/proyecto/codex//pages/science-show-cases/accelerating-expansion.php https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.04495 Detectable within 20 years according to the last of these.

Comment: @ProfRob I don't think we should be holding our breath just yet with regard to these plans to measure the redshift drift in real time. First of all, this is still at least 20 years off, secondly, as the paper points out, it would require to measure the redshift with an accuracy according to a velocity of 1 cm/sec. Now this is a very small velocity and could be caused by many unrelated effects. I remind you only of the spacecraft 'fly-by anomaly' here, which is of the same magnitude, known for 30 years and yet still unresolved.

Comment: @Thomas in what way do your comments address the question or request clarification of the question, which isn't asking about measurements at all?

Comment: @ProfRob Read the question again. The OP remarks that he expects future measurements to show an increase in redshift. I wanted to address the feasibility of such measurements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you cannot apply this equation to the cosmic microwave background and indeed, the redshift of the CMB is increasing with time.

The difference is that the photons we receive from the CMB will always come from a fixed epoch in the universe (the epoch of recombination).

In contrast, the photons that we receive from a distant galaxy were emitted at an epoch that depends on the redshift of the galaxy and this will change with time. In other words, we can watch galaxies getting older. At high redshifts, as a galaxy ages it will experience a *deceleration* in the universal expansion, as we see it, and thus its redshift decreases. At later times and lower redshifts, the expansion accelerates and the redshift increases.

Comment: thanks. Your answer is always helpful. In the case of cosmic background radiation, we always observe fixed points of view, so we have to think differently than in the case of galaxies.

Comment: Just to point out that this is theoretical speculation, based on present cosmological models. Nobody has ever observationalyl measured the change of redshift of the CMB or galaxies with time (and given the time scales required to do this, nobody probably ever will).

Comment: @Thomas indeed redshift drift is a prediction that depends on the cosmological parameters. However, contrary to your statement, there *are* plans to attempt to measure it.

Comment: Yes, results from SKA might be available in 10 or 20 years according to https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.04495

Comment: "At high redshifts, as a galaxy ages it will experience a deceleration in the universal expansion, as we see it, and thus its redshift decreases." Can you please elaborate on this? Isn't the expansion accelerating?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei The universe decelerated until a few billion years ago.

Comment: @ProfRob Could you explain this? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/653465/does-the-cosmological-redshift-of-the-same-object-has-a-same-value-as-it-evolves