# Does the cosmological redshift of the same object has a same value as it evolves

Tags: cosmology, redshift

https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.02444

According to the link above, the following phrase comes out:

" One must keep in mind that in the real universe, the same object( or comoving position) does not take different value of cosmological redshift during its evolution."

However, at the same time according to the above paper, the evolutionary simulation of galaxies shows that the redshift have different values. Please look at the picture below.

[image]

[image]

As far as I know, the value of the red shift of a specific object decreases over time and then increases again.  What does it mean that the red shift value does not change?

+) It seems to point out problems that may arise when using the red shift value as a way to indicate the time instead. In a picture representing the evolutionary simulation of the galaxy, the red shift value simply means time, but be careful because you may not understand it well.

Nevertheless, the paper continues to emphasize that the red-shift value of a particular galaxy remains unchanged. Why won't it change?